# Seeing multiple properties by type on local datastore console

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

I am writing entities using golang in my local data store. When I generate the statistics, I see some of the properties repeat per data type. For example, I have a "status int8" property with noindex but I see "Integer_status_entityname" and "INT64_status_entityname" and the INT64 property has builtin_index_count > 0 while the Integer property has 0. Same is happening for string (with STRING vs Text). Is this a problem with the statics generation or the internal storage itself is some how duplicated by internal data type?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't worry too much, the internals of the local development server emulation and of the real datastore differ quite significantly.

The local emulation will also automatically create some internal entities needed for the emulation itself - those won't be seen in the real datastore.

The official documentation, which describes the real datastore, should be followed when inconsistencies are seen with the local emulation.

When in doubt, just double-check your assumptions and/or the needed functionality when deployed on GAE (there may be some small surprises now and then), adjust if/as needed and move on with your work.

Donno if it's worthy to file issues for small SDK inconsistencies - they would be unnecessary noise while a long list of more important open issues with the SDK and/or GAE itself is still pending.